# Fabric Crashlytics stuck on build and run - IDE error

Tags: android, android-studio, crashlytics, google-fabric

I'm trying to integrate Crashlytics into an Android Application but Fabric plugin stuck on last step. In the past everything works well. **After Android Studio updated to version 3.1.***, I can't integrate Crashlytics into my applications anymore.

Every time I've reached at last step there is an error in my IDE :

```
Write-unsafe context! Model changes are allowed from write-safe contexts only. Please ensure you're using invokeLater/invokeAndWait with a correct modality state (not "any"). See TransactionGuard documentation for details.
  current modality=ModalityState.NON_MODAL
  known modalities:
    ModalityState:{}, writingAllowed=true;
    ModalityState.NON_MODAL, writingAllowed=true
com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger$EmptyThrowable
    at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:140)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.assertWriteActionAllowed(TransactionGuardImpl.java:232)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileDocumentManagerImpl.saveDocument(FileDocumentManagerImpl.java:341)
    at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileDocumentManagerImpl.saveDocument(FileDocumentManagerImpl.java:336)
    at com.crashlytics.tools.ide.app.onboard.IntellijCode$3.run(IntellijCode.java:91)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:762)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:732)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:822)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:650)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:366)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

At line 11 we have :

> com.crashlytics.tools.ide.app.onboard.IntellijCode$3.run(IntellijCode.java:91)

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44661043/fabric-crashlytics-stuck-on-build-and-run) post but it didn't help to solve this problem. Is there any problem with Fabric plugin ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that Fabric plugin have some issues with Android studio **version 3.1**

There isn't any problem with v3.0. I test current project on another system with v3.0 and everything is OK.

Maybe they should prepare an update for plugin